# Meaning Of "Wrapped Around My Finger" and "See Ya When I See Ya"

Tags: speech

Will you help me to understand the meaning of these phrases?

> Wrapped around my finger

and

> See ya when I see ya

Comment: Please include your research with your question.  Did you look these up and then have additional questions?

Answer (score 3):

> Wrapped around my finger

The person who is wrapped around your finger can be persuaded to do anything you want, usually because they like you so much. See [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wrap+around+little+finger)

> See ya when I see ya

This phrase is used in the place of "goodbye." It indicates that you will meet again ("See ya") but it is noncommittal as to the time and date ("when I see ya").